# Storing website visitors without running out of MySQL connections

Tags: mysql, web, connection, visitor-statistic

We have an analytics application which allows users to run a number of different reports.  We have a single master - slave MySQL database setup.

One of the things which we track is visitors on our clients websites.  Everytime a visitor lands on our clients website, we write various information into our master database.  The problem is that we are running out of MySQL database connections during peak traffic times (generally in the evening).  We know we need to somehow stage the visitor data being written.  However one of things which we use to sell this product is that you can see the visitor data whilst they are currently on the website.  We could allow for a short delay (1-2 minutes) between the visitor being on the website and the data being available for the reports.

What is the best way of staging the visitor data?  Is there another way to do this which is scalable?

The query which is causing the locking is:

```
SELECT VisitID,VistSourceID 
FROM visitorvisits 
LEFT JOIN visitornumbers 
ON VinuVlviID=VlviID 
WHERE vistNosID='12345' AND 
VistCampaignID='1' AND 
('2013-04-03 14:30:48' >= DATE_ADD(VistDateStart, INTERVAL VistTimeStart HOUR_SECOND)) 
AND ('2013-04-03 14:30:48' <= DATE_ADD(VistDateEnd, INTERVAL VistTimeEnd HOUR_SECOND) 
OR VistStatusCode='1')
```

The expalin on this stament is:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                    | type   | possible_keys                                                                     | key            | key_len | ref                                          | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | visitornumbers           | ref    | idx_vistNosID,idx_visitNosVisitID                                                     | idx_vistNoID | 4       | const                                        | 4527 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | visitorvisits            | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_VistCampaignID,idx_VistStatusCode,idx_VistCampaignID_VistDateStart_VistVistorID | PRIMARY        | 4       | mhdblive.visitorvisits.visitNosVisitID |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: What's  your website written in? PHP? Ruby? Java?

Comment: Our application is written in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Are you fully closing the connections each time?

If you are and there is no way you can avoid running out of connections then I suspect the solution will be messy.

Possibly write the info to a fixed place such as a text file and have a CRON job that runs every 30 seconds or so to process the contents of that file(s).

Or possibly an HTTP call to a page on your site that stores the data in a session variable array and then wipes the session variables and stores all the details on a table every 30 seconds or so.

Comment: The connection should be closed off fully each time.

Comment: What is your max connections set to? Default is 100 I think, which should cover most fairly busy web sites as long as connections are freed up (assuming nobody is using persistent connections).

Comment: Our max connections is 150 (plus 1 for root).

Comment: Do you really have 150+ concurrent transactions? Each should be taking a fraction of a second. If they are taking much longer than that on average then it suggests the SQL queries are quite slow. Have you checked the slow query log for any frequent slow queries that could be hogging MySQL resources (and hence connections)?

Comment: There is the odd query which we run regulary (every minute), which sometimes can take a few seconds to run, which can lock up the tables.  However we can't understand why this query takes longer than normal at particular times.  It runs regularly but only seems to have a problem once a day - the time of this problem is not consistent.

Comment: Could you post that query and an EXPLAIN for it? If it is locking tables then it could cause a problem, with following queries hogging the connections while waiting. While you could probably increase the max connections settings this might just put the problem off for a bit

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's worth checking the application for connection management bugs - depending on how you connect to MySQL (hint: PDO is pretty much the standard these days), it's possible your code keeps connections open for longer than you need them - especially if you have long-running processes somewhere in the application that keep the database connection open while they run.

Next - check the number of connections that your MySQL server is configured to accept; on Linux, with enough RAM, you should be able to support thousands of open connections; if your application only opens connections when it needs them, that roughly translates to the number of concurrent page requests you're supporting (and each page request should execute in milliseconds). It's possible you're reaching this level, but usually, there are other bottlenecks you reach at that level (database CPU, typically).

If both those things are as good as they are going to get, the standard solution is to create an asynchronous infrastructure - your web page stores the request to write a database record into a queue of some description, and moves on; a second process looks at the queue and handles the writes in whatever way is best.

You can brew your own solution to this, or you can use one of the many queue servers (eg. Beanstalk, Amazon SQS, RabbitMQ).